# How to save canvas on phone and get the location of the image with phonegap?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

What is the way to save a canvas to your phone album (camera roll, etc.) using Phonegap?

And when saved, how do I get the image URL using Cordova? Which plugins should I consider for this?

---

**Method 1: Canvas2Image Plugin**

With [this plugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin), you can save a canvas to your phone library using:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="165px" height="145px"></canvas>

function onDeviceReady()
{
    window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    );
}
```

However, it is not clear how the imageURI is passed or returned after saving?

UPDATE 23/02. I tried the following, but it never reaches my successcallback:

$scope.done = function() {

```
    // todo: iterate over cloaks
    $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Saving images...'
    });


    // #issue: callback is not called
    saveCanvasToPhone().then(successCallback, errorCallback);

    var successCallback = function(output) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();

        window.alert("success call back: " + output) // never reached

        $scope.addNewImage(output);
        $state.go('tab.dash', {}, {reload: true}); // does not work
        $state.go('tab.dash') // does not work

        $scope.refreshLocalstorage();

    }

    // #issue4-nl: not working
    var errorCallback = function(error) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log("error cb: "+ error)
        window.alert("error cb: " + error)
    }

    function saveCanvasToPhone() {



        var defer = $q.defer();

        try {
            window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
            function(output){

                $scope.addNewImage(output); // does not work to save imagepath on localstorage

                $scope.debugEntryOther = output // works fine
                defer.resolve(output)
                $ionicLoading.hide()
            },
            function(error){
                defer.reject(error)
                $ionicLoading.hide()
                window.alert(error)
            },
            document.getElementById('canvas')
        );
        } catch(error) {
                defer.reject(error)
                $ionicLoading.hide()
                console.log("saveCanvasToPhone: trycatch: error: " + error)
        }
        return defer.promise;
    } // save canvas to phone
} // done
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly Canvas2Image plugin was originally designed to save the canvas to the gallery, not to save to a file and deal with the file later on.

I have not found alternatives to this plugin (nor have I really searched), but you can manage to get the file path where the file was saved.

It depends on wich platform you are targeting :

- For android, the path to the file is passed in the parameter 'msg' of the success function
- For Windows Phone, the 'msg' parameter returns the string 'Image saved :' followed with the path of the file. So you have to split the string.
- For IOS, it is actually not possible with the original plugin, but there are several forks allowing to do it.

I was informed that the author will soon take some time to improve his plugin so I'm sure it will soon be possible to get the file path with the 'official' plugin even for IOS.

In the meantime, you could use [my fork](https://github.com/nicolasgrolleau/Canvas2ImagePlugin). In that case, for IOS the path is returned in the 'msg' parameter, just like for android.

Comment: Thanks for that. That sounds worrying. I tried it but it does not reach my successcallback, see my updated post with comments on where it works and where not. Is there maybe another way to deal with a canvas? perhaps convert to image and then a plugin to save images (download from local storage)? so then I would need canvas to image within the browser...?

Comment: Actually you could deal with canvas with only HTML5 but the reason why I needed that plugin was that the support of canvas on android webview wasn't working unless targetting only kitkat devices.